# Set up arm for local access only

Tags: relays

Since two days, I'm running a Tor relay I call [charon](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/1190E9D0222E3DEF7BE8BF8B0BAC73867C6F6ABD). I heard about `arm` that shows you some statistics about your relay, which sounds like a great tool to have.

For it to work, you have to enable the `ControlPort`, which is a password-protected way to control your relay from the outside. I have the idea to enable the ControlPort and set up `arm`, but I want it to be only accessible by localhost, which I will set up an appropriate rule in my firewall for.

Will it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't require additional configuration, by default the [`ControlPort`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) will bind to 127.0.0.1 on the local loopback interface and as such it will only be accessible through the localhost.

You *should* however also include either a `HashedControlPassword` or a `CookieAuthentication` or alternatively use a UNIX socket and use UNIX filesystem permissions to restrict access to the control port, as it not only provides information but allows Tor to be reconfigured.

A control auth cookie is enabled by default on the Tor debian packages at `/var/run/tor/control.authcookie`, as is a ControlPort through a UNIX socket located at `/var/run/tor/control`, which anyone who is a member of the `debian-tor` group can access by issuing the command `arm -s /var/run/tor/control`.

*P.S. Thanks for running a relay!*